# .NET How to Stop a user from deleting the file?

Tags: .net, file-io

I got this exam question "How to Stop a user from deleting the file?" I assume I should use some permission attribute, but which?

Comment: Are you allowed to get other people to do your exams for you? And if so, can we have the resulting qualifications?

Comment: Just hold the handle to this file open.

Comment: David I am studying for an exam, I'm not doing the exam at the moment and asking You to help me cheat.

Answer (score 2):

Use FileInfo and set its .IsReadOnly property.

```
        Dim fi As New FileInfo("c:\temp\temp.txt")
        fi.IsReadOnly = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent a user with administrative rights from deleting a file. After all, he can overtake the file's ownership and change the permissions.

Comment: You can at least make it very difficult while your process is running :D

Comment: @Vladislav: an administrator can kill the process, or just restart the computer.

Comment: Well... that's the thing, your process doesn't _have_ to show up in task manager :P And I'm not even going to comment on your start-up options. But I believe this has gone off-topic.